# Update a dict values with values in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary I want to update:

```
my_dict = {"a":"A", "b":"B"}
```

and a list with the exact same length:

```
my_list = ["D", "E"]
```

I would like to find the most efficient way to update `my_dict` with the values from `my_list` to:

```
{"a":"D", "b":"E"}
```

without having to run multiple for loops or similar. I tried to do this with list comprehensions, but it does not allow multiple statements:

```
{my_dict_key:list_item for my_dict_key in my_dict.keys(), list_item in my_list}
```

Comment: `dict(zip(dic, lis))`

Comment: How are you expecting that only `a` is updated to `D` while leaving `b` intact?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `zip()` with a dictionary-comprehension:

```
{key: value for key, value in zip(my_dict, my_list)}
```

Or just:

```
dict(zip(my_dict, my_list))
```

Comment: you can update dic using `dic.update(...)` and replace `...` with one of the expressions in this answer

Comment: @steviestickman, how does your comment connected to this answer?

Comment: op said `I am trying to ... update dic so that dic == {"a":"D","b":"B"}` @OlvinRoght

Comment: @steviestickman, Dictionary is already updated by assigning it back to `dic`; why do you want to bring in `dic.update` ?

Comment: This assumes dic is iterated in the same order as lis

Comment: @Austin your expressions create a new dictionary but don't update the existing dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

**If you know the order of your dict is the same as the list,** you can use a ranged for loop to go through each key.

```py
for i, key in enumerate(dic):
  dic[key] = lis[i]
```

[Demo](https://repl.it/repls/ScholarlyAchingCgi)

Answer (score -1):

May be it will help

1. First find keys by

```py
    keys=dic.keys()
```

2. Then Update your dictionary with list elements

```py
    for i in range(len(lis)):
        dic[keys[i]]=lis[i]
```

3.The Dictionary will be updated.